# Fastest way to combine multiple CSV files from a blob storage container into one CSV file on another blob storage container in an Azure function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'd like to hear if it's possible can improve the code below to make it run faster (and maybe cheaper) as part of an Azure function for combining multiple CSV files from a source blob storage container into one CSV file on a target blob storage container on Azure by using Python (please note that it would also be fine for me to use another library than pandas if need be)?

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
# Used for getting access to secrets on Azure key vault for authentication purposes
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

vault_url = 'AzureKeyVaultURL'
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credential)
azure_datalake_connection_str = secret_client.get_secret('Datalake_connection_string')

# Connecting to a source Azure blob storage container where multiple CSV files are stored
blob_block_source = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(
conn_str= azure_datalake_connection_str.value,
container_name= "sourceContainerName"
    )

# Connecting to a target Azure blob storage container to where the CSV files from the source should be combined into one CSV file
blob_block_target = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(
conn_str= azure_datalake_connection_str.value,
container_name= "targetContainerName"
    )

# Retrieve list of the blob storage names from the source Azure blob storage container, but only those that end with the .csv file extension
blobNames = [name.name for name in blob_block_source.list_blobs()]
only_csv_blob_names = list(filter(lambda x:x.endswith(".csv") , blobNames)) 

# Creating a list of dataframes - one dataframe from each CSV file found in the source Azure blob storage container 
listOfCsvDataframes = []
for csv_blobname in only_csv_blob_names:
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob_block_source.download_blob(csv_blobname, encoding='utf-8').content_as_text(encoding='utf-8')), encoding = 'utf-8',header=0, low_memory=False)
    listOfCsvDataframes.append(df)

# Contatenating the different dataframes into one dataframe  
df_concat = pd.concat(listOfCsvDataframes, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

# Creating a CSV object from the concatenated dataframe 
outputCSV = df_concat.to_csv(index=False, sep = ',', header = True)

# Upload the combined dataframes as a CSV file (i.e. the CSV files have been combined into one CSV file)
blob_block_target.upload_blob('combinedCSV.csv', outputCSV, blob_type="BlockBlob", overwrite = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Azure Function, you can use Azure Data Factory to concatenate your files.

It will probably have better efficiency with ADF than Azure Functions with pandas.

Take a look at this blog post https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/merge-multiple-files-in-azure-data-factory

If you want to use Azure function, try to concatenate files without using pandas. If all your files have the same columns and the same column order, you can concatenate string directly and remove the header line, if any, of all files but the first.